# Where query after whereHas not work as it should in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In my case I have *channels* table that is in many to many relation with *categories* table.

I want to fetch the channels that their *categories* contain a dynamic value like doing `LIKE` query on title of each category. but I need to check another columns of a *channel* by where clause.

This is a *channel* structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": 87,
    "username": "ch1",
    "title": "ch title",
    "type": "channel",
    "members": 210424,
    "location": "tabriz",
    "created_at": "2017-05-09 01:39:44",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-16 17:19:28",
  }
]
```

To get what I want I run this query:

```
$channels = Channel::orderBy('members', 'desc')
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })
            ->where([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
            ->get();
```

Upper query return me all the *channels* like a query without `whereHas` clause whiles when I use 'whereHas' alone, it return *channels* with in category that I want!

Am I use wrong syntax? Is it true to use `where` and `whereHas` clauses side by side?

**UPDATE:**

I need do `like` query on channel's title or username, so I use `orWhere` but the result is as before! it returns all channels to me! like query without `whereHas` again.
So I use this query to do it,

```
 $channels = Channel::orderBy('members', 'desc')
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })
            ->where([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
            ->orWhere([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['username', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
            ->get();
```

At first I thought the problem is orderBy clause as @exprator sayed, but after adding `orWhere` I understood that `orderBy` is not my issue.

Comment: are you applying where conditions to categories ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Channel::whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })->orderBy('members', 'desc')
```

use the whereHas before the order_by

```
->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('visible', '=', 1)
                      ->where('username', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%')
                       ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%')
                       ->where('members', '>', $members);
            })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's it!

Comment: I need do `like` query on channel's title or username, so I use `orWhere` but the result is as before! it returns all channels to me! like query without `whereHas` again.

Comment: you removed the accept? ok show me the query what you have written and what you need @BehnamAzimi

Comment: I'm sorry but I understood that `orderBy` clause is not my issue, please notice the question update.

Comment: try editing the orWhere like that and check @BehnamAzimi

Comment: No! not what i need yet,

Comment: i am not getting what actually you need, you are using whereHas, where and orWhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146844/discussion-between-behnam-azimi-and-exprator).

Answer (score 1):

Try to just use `->whereHas()` after the `->where()`. You don't need to duplicate anything normally.

```
$channels = Channel::where([
            ['visible', 1],
            ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
            ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
            ['members', '>', $members]])
        ->orWhere([
            ['visible', 1],
            ['username', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
            ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
            ['members', '>', $members]])
        ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
            $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy('members', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Comment: Nice solution, was plucking my hair because I couldn't find anything that worked, had no idea that you have to use it after `where` clause.

Answer (score 1):

`whereHas()` is wrongly used with `where()` and `orWhere()`. after `whereHas` the second and third conditions have to be combined in a sub-routine. Currently  your query will look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE something_where_has 1 AND WHERE something 2 OR WHERE something 3 ..
```

but I think what you wanted is your condition to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE something_where_has 1 AND (WHERE something 2 OR WHERE something 3) ..
```

So this may serve you:

```
->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })
->where(function($q) {
             $q->where([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
             ->orWhere([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['username', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]]);
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by duplicating `whereHas` clause after `orWhere`.
So to fetch the channels that are in categories that I want, I used this query:

```
$channels = Channel::orderBy('members', 'desc')
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })
            ->where([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['title', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
            ->orWhere([
                ['visible', 1],
                ['username', 'LIKE', '%' . $trend . '%'],
                ['location', 'LIKE', '%' . $location . '%'],
                ['members', '>', $members]])
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $category . '%');
            })
            ->get();
```

Maybe it's strange but worked nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Something like this. I think it will work.

```
  $data = $request->all();
   $stateZipCode = ZipCode::query()
            ->where('code', '=', $data['zipCode'])
            ->whereHas('states', function ($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->where('name', $data['state']);
            })
            ->with(['states' => function ($query) use ($data) {
                return $query->where('name', $data['state']);
            }])
            ->first();
```